# How to refactor it to CBV django?

Tags: python, django, refactoring

I'm beginner in CBV and find help to refactor my FBV. Maybe you can show me some examples or advices for it. I also have a problem with DRY principle as you can see.

My FBV:

```
def formen(request):
    html = 'man_index.html'
    ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.sex == 'M':
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(sex=request.user.sex, is_published=True)

        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)


        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 6)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            elements = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            elements = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            elements = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        elements = paginator.get_page(page)


        context = {
            'all_posts': elements,
            'page_range' : paginator.page_range,
        }
    elif request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.sex == 'W':
        return redirect('/forwomen')

    else:
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(sex='M', is_published=True)
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=query)

        paginator = Paginator(queryset, 3)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            elements = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            elements = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            elements = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        elements = paginator.get_page(page)

        context = {
            'all_posts': elements,
            'page_range' : paginator.page_range,
        }

    return render(request, html, context)
```

What methods should I use to refactor it to CVB?

Comment: This looks like an "anti-pattern" view in the first place: you aim to do *too* much in the view. You paginate by 6 for an authenticated man, and 3 if not authenticated (or not man nor woman). Are you sure the view itself is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a *list view*, so we can write a subclass of the [**`ListView`** [django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) class:

from django.views.generic.list import ListView

```
class ForMenView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'man_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_posts'
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        qs = Post.objects.filter(sex='M', is_published=True)
        if query:
            return qs.filter(title__icontains=query)
        return qs

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated and user.sex == 'M':
            return 6
        return self.paginate_by

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated and user.sex == 'W':
            return redirect('/forwomen')  # please replace it with the view name
        else:
            return super(ArticleListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['page_range'] = kwargs['paginator'].page_range
        return kwargs
```

But the function based view shows some strange things:

1. the path of the authenticated users that are woman is hardcoded, it is better to specify the name (or reference to the function) of the view;
2. it is rather odd that the pagination depends on the fact whether a user is logged in or not;
3. it is rather strange to have a separate view for woman anyway. If the changes are marginal, it is better to merge it into one view;
4. it is rather strange to have a reference to the `paginator.page_range` as separate variable, since by using a reference to the paginator itself, one can access more attributes.

Not all can be solved with this class-based view, since I do not know the details of the `/forwoman`, etc. You thus can see it as *advice* how to refactor it further.

Comment: Oh man, Thank you a lot, you could explain me a lot of staff in your answer. 1. Yes, I used to do it, but this is just prototype view. 2. Yes, You're right. I have the mistake on it. It has the same pagination for aut/not auth user. 3. I have separeting system of site which litteraly means that Men will not be able to visit Women pages and conversely. 4. I used to do it for my comfort but yes I should use paginator itself.